# how to connect UIAlertView with what happens when the user makes a choice?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have code setting up a UIAlertView:

```
-(IBAction)showMessage
{
//NSInteger *buttonIndex = NULL;
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
message:nil 
delegate:nil 
cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
otherButtonTitles:@"Email",@"SMS",@"Facebook",@"Twitter", nil];
[message show];
}
```

and code explaining what to do once the user makes a choice:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        [self openMail];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
//etc.
}
```

But what I can't figure out is how to connect the two.  The obvious answer is to add a line to the first piece of code calling `alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex` on `UIAlertView *message`, but how do you assign `buttonIndex`?  How do you tell `alertView` whether the user has chosen Facebook, Email, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add  to the header file if you haven't already:

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
}
```

...etc

and in your AlertView code change delegate:nil to delegate:self

For more information have a look at the Apple Docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

From the docs:
*The button indices start at 0. If this is the cancel button index, the alert view is canceling. If -1, the cancel button index is not set.*

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was just talking this morning to a friend about how I was finally beginning to understand delegates, but obviously I have a ways to go....

Comment: Okay, but now I'm confused, because, though `[self alertView:message clickedButtonAtIndex:0];` works fine in `showMessage`, `if ([self alertView:message clickedButtonAtIndex:0]) { //etc.` produces an error with the message, `Statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid).`  What am I missing?

Comment: try : if ([[self alertView:message clickedButtonAtIndex] == 0]) { //etc. I am not on my Mac to test it out but maybe that would work

Comment: Ok I logged into my Mac at home and I can get NSLog statements to work fine with this method:  
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  
{  
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {  
        NSLog(@"Button 1");  
    } else if (buttonIndex == 2) {  
        NSLog(@"Button 2");  
    }  
}  
try putting what you need to execute within the appropriate if statement for the button index

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15104/discussion-between-nathan-dries-and-joel-derfner)

Answer (score 1):

(1) You want to set `delegate:self` when you initialize the message. Also, in your interface declaration, do something like:

`@interface myClass: UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>`

This way, your handler function automatically gets called when the user makes a selection.

(2) Buttons are indexed in the order you listed them.

(3) Since you have a lot of options for the user to choose from, it is better to use UIActionSheet instead of UIAlertView. Alerts are generally used for simple Yes/No-type selections.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks--but even with that, I'm still having trouble:  Though `[self alertView:message clickedButtonAtIndex:0];` works fine in showMessage, `if ([self alertView:message clickedButtonAtIndex:0]) { //etc.` produces an error with the message, `Statement requires expression of scalar type ('void' invalid)`. Any ideas about what I'm missing?